# Simple Ajax script for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do you use an ajax script on an iPhone app?

I have a jquery script on my webpage that i would like to be on the view controller for my new app.

```
<jquery...code...>
```

Lets pretend the above is the jqueury code. How would i port this over to the iPhone view controller? Thanks sorry the question is so simple.

(all the code does is display a loading box that spins around and around and its quite pretty. Im probably going to put an image inside it )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to port code that isn't given. We don't port large chunks of code in the first place, and we certainly can't port code we haven't seen.

Comment: ok i will post the query in about 15 minutes. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a `UIWebView` in which case you simply embed a web page (including the JS code) into your app, jQuery (or rather Javascript and the DOM) is completely distinct from Objective-C and Cocoa Touch, so you can't use it, and the only option is to rewrite the same code in the new language and framework.

Comment: sounds doable. Ill repost the code in about 15 thankss